# Verifying Twilio Requests in Apex

Tags: twilio

The Twilio documentation includes detailed instructions for [verifying that requests are actually coming from Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/security#validating-requests), based on a process for building and validating an HMAC-SHA1 hash:

> ...Compare your hash to ours, submitted in the X-Twilio-Signature header. If they match, then you're good to go.

They also say that:

> All of the official Twilio Helper Libraries ship with a Utilities class which facilitates request validation. Head over to the libraries page to download the library for your language of choice.

... but I can't find that utility in the [twilio-salesforce helper library](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-salesforce/tree/master/src).  Can you help?  Do you know of an implementation of this algorithm in Apex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the official method to validate the `x-twilio-signature`. This method need to be implemented to the url (Salesforce site rest resource apex class) on which Twilio sends request to check if the request is actually from Twilio server.

```
    public boolean validateRequest(String expectedSignature, String url, Map<String,String> params) 
    {
               try 
               {
                     // sort the params alphabetically, and append the key and value of each to the url
                    String data = url;        
                    if(params!=null)
                    {
                        List<String> sortedKeys = new List<String>(params.keySet());
                        sortedKeys.sort();

                        for (String s: sortedKeys) {
                            data += s;
                            String v='';
                            if (params.get(s)!=null)
                                v=params.get(s);
                            data += v;
                        }
                    }

                    //compute the hmac on input data bytes, with AuthToken as key
                    Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA1', Blob.valueOf(data), Blob.valueOf(authToken));

                    //base64-encode the hmac
                    String signature = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);

                    return signature.equals(expectedSignature);
               } 
               catch (Exception e)
               {
                    return false;
               }
}
```

This is how Twilio created signature at server side:

> - Turn on SSL on your server and configure your Twilio account to use HTTPS urls.
> - Twilio assembles its request to your application, including the final URL and any POST fields (if the request is a POST).
> - If your request is a POST, Twilio takes all the POST fields, sorts them by alphabetically by their name, and concatenates the parameter
>     name and value to the end of the URL (with no delimiter).
> - Twilio takes the resulting string (the full URL with query string and all POST parameters) and signs it using HMAC-SHA1 and your
>     AuthToken as the key.
> - Twilio sends this signature in an HTTP header called X-Twilio-Signature

This is how it can be validate on our end:

> - Take the full URL of the request URL you specify for your phone number or app, from the protocol (https...) through the end of the
>     query string (everything after the ?).
> - If the request is a POST, sort all of the POST parameters alphabetically (using Unix-style case-sensitive sorting order).
> - Iterate through the sorted list of POST parameters, and append the variable name and value (with no delimiters) to the end of the URL
>     string.
> - Sign the resulting string with HMAC-SHA1 using your AuthToken as the key (remember, your AuthToken's case matters!).
> - Base64 encode the resulting hash value. Compare your hash to ours, submitted in the X-Twilio-Signature header. If they match, then you're
>     good to go.

**Note:** Referenced from Twilio official documentation. Method is there already, in `classes/TwilioRestClient.cls`

Comment: Do you want to submit it as a contribution to the twilio library so others can benefit as well? https://github.com/twilio/twilio-salesforce/tree/master/src

Comment: OK - I just noticed it's there already, in `classes/TwilioRestClient.cls`   This detail is great, but it would have been enough to point me over there.

Comment: Yes, Its already added.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is already in the twilio library - I have a SFDC/Twilio integration that uses that.

My github repo is here, which uses a slimmed down Twilio library just to support SMS
https://github.com/britishboyindc/TextToCase_Twilio_Salesforce

And here's the REST class that receives the Twilio message and checks the signature:
https://github.com/britishboyindc/TextToCase_Twilio_Salesforce/blob/master/src/classes/smsToApex.cls